# Despite of and in spite of

Tags: word-usage, difference

> In **despite** of them being rich they wanted more

could this be a correct sentence? If not, why ? And what is the correction

Comment: The sentence is incorrect, as it mixes up two idioms.  See Ross Murray's answer for how these two idioms should be used.

Answer (score 2):

There is a usage note about 'despite' in CMoS 5.220

> **despite;in spite of.** For brevity, prefer *despite*.

So, this is acceptable:

> "In spite of them being rich, they wanted more."

This is better:

> "Despite them being rich, they wanted more."

Comment: I just noticed this is the first question by the poster. CMoS is an acronym for the Chicago Manual of Style. It is the highest selling guide in America for things such as the correct use of punctuation and various aspects of grammar and publishing.